# Bigcommerce Stencil order of stylesheets causing error

Tags: node.js, sass, bigcommerce, node-sass

I know this will be nearly impossible to answer given that I am unable to reliably reproduce the problem on a clean install of the default Stencil theme, but I've been at it for hours trying to understand what's going on. I'm hoping someone can suggest any ideas they have that might be the cause of the problem so I can try to investigate it from a different angle.

Here is the full content of my main `assets/scss/theme.scss` file:

```
// Foundation CSS Framework
@import 'settings';
@import '../../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/foundation';
@include foundation-everything;

// Custom Settings
@import 'customSettings';

// Libraries
@import '../../node_modules/magnific-popup/src/css/main';
@import '../../node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick';

// Custom Mixins
@import 'mixins';

// Utilities
@import 'utilities/utilities';

// Layouts
@import 'layouts/html';
@import 'layouts/header';
@import 'layouts/body';
@import 'layouts/footer';
@import 'layouts/home';
@import 'layouts/container';
@import 'layouts/category';
@import 'layouts/product';
@import 'layouts/cart';

// Components
@import 'components/type';
@import 'components/button';
@import 'components/panel';
@import 'components/callout';
@import 'components/carousel';
@import 'components/scrollTop';
@import 'components/modal';
@import 'components/topBanner';
@import 'components/mainNav';
@import 'components/headerInfo';
@import 'components/helpDropdown';
@import 'components/pageHeading';
@import 'components/icons';
@import 'components/breadcrumbs';
@import 'components/categoryImages';
@import 'components/rating';
@import 'components/productPrice';
@import 'components/productCard';
@import 'components/productGrid';
@import 'components/socialLinks';
@import 'components/referralProgram';
@import 'components/homeReviews';
@import 'components/homeCopy';
@import 'components/categorySort';
@import 'components/sidebarBlock';
@import 'components/pagination';
@import 'components/productHeader';
@import 'components/productHeaderBullets';
@import 'components/productOption';
@import 'components/productContentPreviewBox';
@import 'components/productMenubar';
@import 'components/productSubsection';
@import 'components/productDetails';
@import 'components/productFaqs';
@import 'components/productVideos';
@import 'components/productReviews';
@import 'components/scrollTop';
@import 'components/cart';
@import 'components/cartHeader';
@import 'components/cartButtons';
@import 'components/shippingEstimator';
@import 'components/cartCallouts';
@import 'components/cartProductSection';
@import 'components/loadingOverlay';
@import 'components/page';
```

This file is included in the head of my `template/layout/base.html` file like so:

```
{{{stylesheet '/assets/css/theme.css'}}}
```

When I load my site, everything works as expected. The page loads the stylesheet correctly after the stencil server compiles it to css at `http://localhost:3000/stencil/theme/1/css/theme.css`.

Next, I create another scss file called `assets/scss/testing.scss`. Here is the full content of that file:

```
@import 'settings';

.page-content {

  .formContainer {
    background-color: $light-gray;
    border: 1px solid $dark-gray;
    padding: 1rem;
    max-width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:40px;
  }

  button {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

I then include this file in the head of my main layout just under the call for `theme.css`, like this:

```
{{{stylesheet '/assets/css/theme.css'}}}
{{{stylesheet '/assets/css/testing.css'}}}
```

Now, when I refresh the page, I see the following 2 issues:

1) The stencil cli command line outputs the following error:

```
{ [Error: ../../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/foundation.scss doesn't exist!]
  formatted: 'Error: ../../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/foundation.scss doesn\'t exist!\n        on line 3 of stdin\n>> @import \'../../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/foundation\';\n   --------^\n',
  message: '../../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/foundation.scss doesn\'t exist!',
  column: 9,
  line: 3,
  file: 'stdin',
  status: 1 }
```

2) The browser gets an error when trying to load the `theme.css` file. The status is `422 Unprocessable Entity`. However, if I navigate my browser directly to `http://localhost:3000/stencil/theme/1/css/theme.css`, the css file is there, and looks to have been compiled correctly.

Now, if I switch the order of the stylesheet calls in my layout file, like this, everything loads correctly:

```
{{{stylesheet '/assets/css/testing.css'}}}
{{{stylesheet '/assets/css/theme.css'}}}
```

The error completely goes away and never shows up no matter how many times I refresh the page. As soon as I switch back to the original order and refresh the page, the errors show up again.

Even more strange, it seems that the command line error always references the first `@import` statement in `theme.scss` that does not exist in `testing.scss`. For example, if I were to now add the second line from `theme.scss` to `testing.scss`, the error will change to now reference the third import in `theme.scss`. In other words, if I change the imports at the top of `testing.scss` to:

```
@import 'settings';
@import '../../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/foundation';
```

The command line error now reads:

```
{ [Error: customSettings.scss doesn't exist!]
  formatted: 'Error: customSettings.scss doesn\'t exist!\n        on line 7 of stdin\n>> @import \'customSettings\';\n   --------^\n',
  message: 'customSettings.scss doesn\'t exist!',
  column: 9,
  line: 7,
  file: 'stdin',
  status: 1 }
```

If I add `customSettings` to the import list, the error moves to the next one:

```
@import 'settings';
@import '../../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/foundation';
@import 'customSettings';

{ [Error: ../../node_modules/magnific-popup/src/css/main.scss doesn't exist!]
  formatted: 'Error: ../../node_modules/magnific-popup/src/css/main.scss doesn\'t exist!\n        on line 10 of stdin\n>> @import \'../../node_modules/magnific-popup/src/css/main\';\n   --------^\n',
  message: '../../node_modules/magnific-popup/src/css/main.scss doesn\'t exist!',
  column: 9,
  line: 10,
  file: 'stdin',
  status: 1 }
```

This pattern continues all the way down the list until I've included every import from `theme.css` in `testing.css`. At that point, the errors go away. The error also goes away if at any point throughout this process I change the order of the stylesheets in the layout so that `testing.css` comes before `theme.scss`.

To make things even worse, this behavior isn't 100% consistent. It happens consistently **most** of the time, but there have been random times where I restart the server or refresh the page after not refreshing it for a while, and things work correctly, but as soon as I refresh again, the errors come back.

To me this feels like some sort of issue with the stencil server and it caching data or something like that. As I said, I can't reproduce it on a fresh install of the default stencil theme so I realize this is basically impossible to get help with, but at this point I don't know where else to turn.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but in case anyone else lands here looking for a fix...
Our BigCommerce themes sporadically experienced the same issue and a fix has been added to the stencil-cli package today that addresses the issue.

Issue: https://github.com/bigcommerce/stencil-cli/issues/404
Commit: https://github.com/bigcommerce/stencil-cli/pull/436

If you **update stencil-cli to >= v1.15.5 the issue should be resolved**.

Credit to https://github.com/2ps for the commit.